# Stop scrolling at some point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im having a problem making an div stop scrolling at a certain point. I've looked at others solutions but i cant make it work on mine. Anybody care to take a look and tell me what i've done wrong?

My code's:

```js
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function(pos) {
  var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw);

  $window.scroll(function(e) {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
      $this.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: pos
      });
    } else {
      $this.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0
      });
    }
  });
};

$('#header').followTo(250);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Index*/

#index {
  background-image: url(../img/metallica/Metallica_London_2008-09-15_Kirk_and_JamesBL.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 10;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#venstre {
  float: left;
}
#midt {
  float: left;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
}
#header a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif, 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  font-size: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 650px;
  position: relative;
}
#header form {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-right: 49px;
}
#righto {
  float: right;
}
#lefto {
  float: left;
}
#Wrapper {
  clear: both;
}
.anker {
  width: 67px;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 147px;
  margin-top: 207px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}
.anker a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.anker ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.undercirkel {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.undercirkelt {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 800px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.box {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  margin-top: 187px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -1;
}
.boxt {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -1;
}
.dropdown {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 190px;
}
.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif, 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #282828;
}
.dropdown ul a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.drop {
  background-color: #393939;
  border: #D4D4D4;
}
.drop li:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  border: #D4D4D4;
}
.undermenu {
  display: none;
}
.undermenu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.undermenu li {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #393939;
}
.dropdown li:hover .undermenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown li:hover .undermenu li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.dropdown ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
#right {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 52px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 1250px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
#right img {
  padding: 15px;
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rockentusiasterne</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/js.js"></script>
  <script>
    var windw = this;

    $.fn.followTo = function(pos) {
      var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

      $window.scroll(function(e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
          $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
          });
        } else {
          $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 40
          });
        }
      });
    };

    $('#scrollto-menu-nav').followTo(250);
  </script>
</head>

<body id="index">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="lefto"><a href="index.html">Rockentusiasterne</a>
    </div>
    <div id="righto">
      <form>
        <label>
          <img src="../img/search.png">
        </label>
        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Søg">
        </input>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="left">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Forside</a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Genrer</a>
              <ul class="undermenu">
                <li><a href="#">Rock'n'Roll</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Alternativ musik</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Grunge</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Om os</a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
              <ul class="undermenu">
                <li><a href="#">Opret bruger</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt os</a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="innerwrapper">
      <div id="midt">
        <div class="anker">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#1">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <li>
              <a href="#2">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <li>
              <a href="3">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <li>
              <a href="4">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a name="1"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>

        <div class="boxt">
          <a name="2"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <img src="../img/metallica/Metallica-on-Howard-Stern-Show-Wallpaper.png" width="81" height="60">
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unbind the scroll event**. Something like

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where would you put it?

Comment: Anywhere inside scroll function. After following upto 250, he does not want to scroll so better unbind it Or need to add extra logic (if else statement) inside window.scroll function to unbind on certain condition.